# LSMS Segmentation OTB

Tags: qgis, image-segmentation, feature-extraction, otb-applications, mean-shift

How can I change the directory of the created file during Large Scale Mean Shift Segmentation (OTB) in QGIS. [image: It will still have so many so many file created on my desktop even though I already set my output directory in a folder.]

QGIS version: 3.28.4-Firenze
QGIS code revision: fd0fb72ab3
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.6.2
GEOS version: 3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.1.1, December 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.4.3 (git-version: f8d673)
Algorithm started at: 2024-01-29T11:31:07
Algorithm 'LargeScaleMeanShift' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'in' : 'C:/Users/antaragrafik/Desktop/Data/AFE/QGIS/Image/5K_Tiff/AU42191.tif', 'spatialr' : 5, 'ranger' : 15, 'minsize' : 50, 'tilesizex' : 500, 'tilesizey' : 500, 'mode' : 'vector', 'mode.vector.imfield' : None, 'mode.vector.out' : 'C:/Users/antaragrafik/Desktop/LargeScaleMeanShiftSegmentation/AU42191.shp', 'cleanup' : True, 'outputpixeltype' : 5 }

2024-01-29 11:31:12 (INFO) LargeScaleMeanShift: Default RAM limit for OTB is 256 MB
2024-01-29 11:31:12 (INFO) LargeScaleMeanShift: GDAL maximum cache size is 1632 MB
2024-01-29 11:31:12 (INFO) LargeScaleMeanShift: OTB will use at most 8 threads
2024-01-29 11:31:12 (INFO) LargeScaleMeanShift: Smoothing step...
2024-01-29 11:31:12 (INFO): Loading metadata from official product
2024-01-29 11:31:12 (INFO) LargeScaleMeanShift: Margin of 501 pixels applied to each tile to stabilized mean shift filtering.

2024-01-29 11:31:12 (INFO) LargeScaleMeanShift: Mode Search is disabled.

2024-01-29 11:31:12 (INFO) LargeScaleMeanShift: Number of tiles: 86 x 86
2024-01-29 11:31:12 (INFO) LargeScaleMeanShift: Tile shifting ...
2024-01-29 11:31:24 (INFO): File AU42191_0_0_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:31:33 (INFO): File AU42191_0_1_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:31:43 (INFO): File AU42191_0_2_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:31:55 (INFO): File AU42191_0_3_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:32:03 (INFO): File AU42191_0_4_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:32:14 (INFO): File AU42191_0_5_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:32:21 (INFO): File AU42191_0_6_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:32:26 (INFO): File AU42191_0_7_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:32:31 (INFO): File AU42191_0_8_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:32:36 (INFO): File AU42191_0_9_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:32:40 (INFO): File AU42191_0_10_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:32:45 (INFO): File AU42191_0_11_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:32:51 (INFO): File AU42191_0_12_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:32:56 (INFO): File AU42191_0_13_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:33:02 (INFO): File AU42191_0_14_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:33:07 (INFO): File AU42191_0_15_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:33:12 (INFO): File AU42191_0_16_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:33:20 (INFO): File AU42191_0_17_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:33:25 (INFO): File AU42191_0_18_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:33:30 (INFO): File AU42191_0_19_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:33:37 (INFO): File AU42191_0_20_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:33:46 (INFO): File AU42191_0_21_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:33:55 (INFO): File AU42191_0_22_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:34:03 (INFO): File AU42191_0_23_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:34:13 (INFO): File AU42191_0_24_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:34:22 (INFO): File AU42191_0_25_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:34:31 (INFO): File AU42191_0_26_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:34:39 (INFO): File AU42191_0_27_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:34:49 (INFO): File AU42191_0_28_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:34:59 (INFO): File AU42191_0_29_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:35:11 (INFO): File AU42191_0_30_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:35:20 (INFO): File AU42191_0_31_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels
2024-01-29 11:35:29 (INFO): File AU42191_0_32_SEG.tif will be written in 1 blocks of 501x501 pixels